# How to find difference between two strings?

Tags: c#, string, word-diff

I have two strings and would like to display the difference between them. For example, if I have the strings "I am from Mars" and "I am from Venus", the output could be "I am from **Venus**". (Typically used to show what changed in an audit log, etc.)

Is there a simple algorithm for this? I am using C# but I guess a generic algorithm could be adapted from any programming language.

Or is there a framework class/third-party library that will do this sort of thing?

Comment: string.Replace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517571/difference-between-two-strings-c-sharp

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm

Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

There is also an implementation described here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DiffAlgorithmCS.aspx