# Difference between two strings C#

Tags: c#, string

Lets say I have two strings:

```
string s1 = "hello";
string s2 = "hello world";
```

Is there a way I can get a `string s3 = " world";` which is the difference between the 2 strings?

**EDIT:**

The difference will be always in this scenario

```
s1 = "abc"
s2 = "abcd ads as "
```

Comment: You would need to more clearly define difference.  What about scenario of `s1 = "hello!"` and `s2 = "hello world!"`?  Or `s1 = "bob the builder"` and `s2 = "the bob"`?  Does one always contain just an exact substring of the other string?

Comment: what about more complicated differences... say, "abc" vs "1bC4"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `string s3 = s2.Replace(s1, "");`

**EDIT:** Note that all occurrences of `s1` in `s2` will be absent from `s3`. Make sure to carefully consider the comments on this post to confirm this is your desired result, for example the scenarios mentioned in [@mellamokb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb)'s comment.

Comment: Just remember that if s1 appears more than once in s2 that there could be a problem.  If s2="hello hello" then this would return just a space as "hello" is matched multiple times.

Comment: @JB King - Agreed, I think more information is need from the OP about what exactly "difference" means. +1 to the comment by mellamokb

Answer (score 6):

```
string s1 = "hello";
string s2 = "hello world";
string s3 = s2.replace(s1,"");
```

Comment: You are second highest in answering this, I tried to put  my answer but there are 2 answers already

Answer (score 5):

With a simple replace

```
string s3 = s2.Replace(s1, "");
```

Answer (score 5):

If the case you define is correct an alternative solution would be:

```
string s3 = s2.substring(s1.Length);
```

This is presuming that the second string begins with exactly the same characters as the first string and you merely want to chop off the initial duplication.

Answer (score 2):

IF (big "if") `s1` is always a substring of `s2`, then you could work with [`.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) and [`.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) to find where in `s2` that `s1` is.

Answer (score 1):

First answer without conditions outside of the code:

```
string s3 = null;
if (s2.StartsWith(s1))
{
    s3 = s2.Substring(s1.Length);
}
```