# Findings the Unmatched Strings

Tags: c#

Lets say that I have two strings:

1. "The System is in halt state."
2. "The System is in [A] state."

Is it possible to find the difference between the two strings ,I need both [A] and halt as output.

As of now i'm splitting every word and check for the match.

Is there any better way...?

Comment: Similar question (and answer) can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208094/how-to-find-difference-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string a = "The System is in halt state.";
            string b = "The System is in [A] state.";

```
        var vardiff =( a.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Except(b.Split(new char[] { ' ' }))).ToList<string>();
        var vardiff1 = (b.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Except(a.Split(new char[] { ' ' }))).ToList<string>();
```

Comment: will it not fail if the 2nd line is "The System is in [A] Marina state."  ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:[Diff Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm)

Also: [Longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

There is also an implementation described here: [sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DiffAlgorithmCS.aspx)

Comment: ganeeesh. pathutaen da,, i have used  Longest common sub sequence logic dhan da.. Is there any Regular Expression ?..

Answer (score 0):

Really, the question isn't entirely clear on what you mean by "difference". Is it simply the number of characters that are the same, or a more heuristic way of comparing unmatched strings?

One algorithm you might want to explore is the [Approximate String Comparisons Using Levenshtein Distance](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/approximate-string-comparisons-using-levenshtein-distance).