# C# compare bytes using bitwise operations

Tags: c#, compare, arrays, byte, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to write a method in C# that will return the difference between two byte arrays by comparing each byte in the arrays and returning the byte from the second if it is different from the first.  I have this so far:

```
        byte[] b1 = 111;
        byte[] b2 = 105;

        int j = input.Length;

        byte[] differenceByte = new byte[j];

        int diffIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            if (originalByte[i] != comparisonByte[i])
                differenceByte[diffIndex++] = comparisonByte[i];
        }
```

But I was hoping to find a way to replace the if statement comparing the first byte to the second with some bitwise voodoo magic...  Is there a way to do this?

A second question is there any other way to optimize this code so that it will run as fast as possible?

I would ultimately like to use this code to compare two strings by converting the strings to and from an array of bytes, so if there is something I should know about in that respect, that would also be helpful.

Comment: It would help if you could give us more context of the bigger picture here. Why would you want to convert the strings to bytes, instead of comparing characters, for example?

Comment: If you're looking for a "string diff," maybe check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208094/how-to-find-difference-between-two-strings).

Comment: Are you considering Unicode and multi-byte encodings? Because characters are not bytes, some characters may span to multiple bytes.

Comment: You could use the exclusive OR operator: `(originalByte[i] ^ comparisonByte[i] > 0)`.  It certainly wouldn't clarify the code.  Performance might decrease, but it's worth it for the obfuscation.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was converting to bytes because I was thinking there might be a way to use bitwise operators to get what is different between the strings, but I can tell I'm going to have to rethink this thing completely.  Thanks for all the suggestions, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality operators operate on bits.
There is no bitwise voodoo magic that will improve equality operators.

Comment: Alright, I'll probably redesign using characters like Jon said