# How to Send / Receive message in Paltalk

Tags: c#

Is it possible to send and receive programmatically messages via Paltalk?

I find a library on the internet, but doesn't send Text.

I use C# 6.0
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331205/comparing-two-pdf-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Please add a link to the library where you found it and add other details if you can.

Comment: I find it here : http://www.pickmike.com/common/node.aspx?pid=10